# Arduino C++ file - class instantiation fails when setting a private member variable in the constructor

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using the Arduino IDE 1.0.5-r2 and trying to create a class with two member variables, _pinA and _pinB. When I call the constructor from my Arduino sketch, I get this error:

`RotaryEncoderReader.cpp:6: error: request for member '_pinB' in 'this', which is of non-class type 'RotaryEncoderReader* const'`

The constructor can be called from a regular C++ files compiled using GCC, and there are no errors. Am I missing something about how to use a class constructor with an Arduino?

Here is the class header:

```
#ifndef RotaryEncoderReader_h
#define RotaryEncoderReader_h

#include "Arduino.h"
class RotaryEncoderReader {
    private:
        int _pinA;
        int _pinB;
        volatile long encoderPos;

    public:
        RotaryEncoderReader( int newPinA, int newPinB );
        void doEncoderA();
        void doEncoderB();
        long getPosition();
};
#endif
```

Here's the implementation:

```
#include "RotaryEncoderReader.h"

RotaryEncoderReader::RotaryEncoderReader( int newPinA, int newPinB )
    : _pinA(newPinA),
      _pinB(newPinB),
      encoderPos(0)
{
}

void RotaryEncoderReader::doEncoderA()
{
    //Irrelevant
}

void RotaryEncoderReader::doEncoderB()
{
    //Irrelevant
}


long RotaryEncoderReader::getPosition()
{
    return _pinA + _pinB;
}
```

And here's the Arduino sketch:

```
#include <RotaryEncoderReader.h>

int pinA = 2;
int pinB = 3;

RotaryEncoderReader reader(pinA, pinB);

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```